# how to print the median of a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I've written code to find the median of a list but I'm unsure how to display it when I run the code.
I've tried the print function but I'm not sure what to print.

My code is:

```
wages = [1,2,3]

def median(wages):
    sorted_list = sorted(wages)
    length = len(sorted_list)
    center = length // 2


    if length == 1:
        return sorted_list[0]

    elif length % 2 == 0:
        return sum(sorted_list[center - 1: center + 1]) / 2.0

    else:
        return sorted_list[center]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sidenote:yYou can remove `  if length == 1: return sorted_list[0]` - that is just a special case of `return sorted_list[center]`  .. or do a `return sorted_list[center] if lenght % 2 == 1 else sum(sorted_list[center - 1: center + 1]) / 2.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can just print the return value of your `median` method.

```
def median():
    your code here   

print(median())
```

PS : There are some indentation errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call your function in the print statement:

```
print(median(wages))
```

or

```
print(median([1,2,3])
```

You might be confused because you labelled wages as the array and put it in the definition of your function, but there is no connection between the two `wages` in your code. The line

```
wages = [1,2,3]
```

creates a variables called wages but it doesn't impact the wages in the line:

```
def median(wages):
```

or inside your function definition. To read more have a look into variable scopes in python.

For example, you could call your function on any array such as,

```
test_array = [1,2,3,4]
print(median(test_array))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Annoyed at myself for not that!

Comment: @TJKeets90 Glad I could help.